# Move head and tail 1 step in a List

Tags: python, list, syntax

If I have the big list A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
and I have sub lists of 3 elements e.g

B = [1,2,3]

I want to slide 1 step forward according to the A list so B becomes [2,3,4] - is there a smooth way to do this? Or do i just have to pop the first element of B and then append the proper element from A?

Thanks!

EDIT: My answer
B = A[i:i+3]
Where you can increase 'i' if you want to view forward by 'i' steps.

Comment: Is `B = A[1:4]` what you're after? Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, so basically B = A[i:3+i]
Where i = 0, and the size of the chunk will be 3 elements then.
Then I can increment 'i' with 1 if I want to move. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can make `A` a `deque`:

```
from collections import deque
A = deque(range(1,11))
```

And `B` can be a view of the first 3 elements of `A`.  When you need to "slide", rotate `A` to the left.

```
A
Out[71]: deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

from itertools import islice #deques do not support slicing notation
B = list(islice(A,3))

B
Out[74]: [1, 2, 3]

A.rotate(-1)
B = list(islice(A,3))

B
Out[77]: [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Okay, a "View" that was the word I was looking for thanks. So is this faster than the B = A[i:3+i] thingy, dont know what the ":" is named.

Ehm, what about that "Out[71] , 74, 77" What is 71?

Comment: `Out` is just ipython, my interpreter, labeling output line numbers.  As for "faster" I highly doubt your application is going to be bottlenecked by either operation, both are extremely fast.  Use whatever makes most sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    b = a[i:i+3]
    print b 

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
```

You can make more generally.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for B in (A[i - 3: i] for i in range(3, len(A) + 1)):
...     print B
... 
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, izip
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for l in izip(*(islice(A, x, None) for x in xrange(3))):
...     print list(l)
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
```

`islice(A, x, None)` creates an iterator over `A[x:]`.